# What is the correct way to say: Collected data from acts/laws and from <ministry counterparts> via phone and email?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I am not sure how to properly put this in a sentence. While working as a policy research assistant for a provincial government ministry [e.g., Alberta Ministry of Mineral Resources], I collected data for my research work from two sources: (1) the acts and regulations of all provinces [websites] and (2) from policy analysts/economists working at the ministry counterparts [trying so say the equivalent mines/minerals ministries in other provinces] via phone and email communication.

As you can see (2) is very confusing and not clear. Those people are not working over phone. I collected data from them over phone and email. More importantly, not sure if "ministry counterparts" is the correct phrase. What is the best way to write the second part so it is clear. My current version is the following:

> Collected data from mining and mineral resources acts and regulations of all provinces and territories and from policy analysts/economists working at the ministry counterparts via phone and email communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest the following. I have bracketed elements that might be omitted without changing the essential meaning.

I collected data (for my research) from two sources, firstly (via internet searches) from the legislation and regulations governing mining and mineral resources of all provinces and territories, and secondly (by phone and email communication) from policy analysts and economists employed in (relevant) provincial ministries.